# AmChart showing wrong values or uneeded

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

How can i change edit or change the 12:00 in my chart ? is not needed and also takes alot of space, i tried all the ways i could do, but is not going away and am trying to get the data to show from API, own made API. please help ?

Chart js code :

```
   <script>
    // Haetan data omasta APistä 
    fetch('https://users.metropolia.fi/~noorja/WSK12021/OTIUM02-offical/OTIUM02/API/hrv.php')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            // Themes begin
            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
            // Themes end

            // Create chart
            var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
            chart.paddingRight = 20;

            chart.data = data;
            chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "MM-dd";

            var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
            dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
            dateAxis.baseInterval = {
                timeUnit: "MM-dd",
                count: 1
            };

            var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
            valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

            var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
            series.dataFields.dateX = "day";
            series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
            series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
            series.strokeWidth = 3;

            chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
            chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
            chart.cursor.fullWidthLineX = true;
            chart.cursor.lineX.strokeWidth = 0;
            chart.cursor.lineX.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(2);
            chart.cursor.lineX.fillOpacity = 0.1;

            chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

        });
</script>
```

API file :

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 

//Tästä voi käytä tietokanta ja sessioita 
 $data1 = array(
array("day"=> "04-21",
"value"=> 3),

array("day"=> "04-22",
"value"=> 4),

array("day"=> "04-23",
"value"=> 3),

array("day"=> "04-24",
"value"=> 2),

array("day"=> "04-25",
"value"=> 5),

array("day"=> "04-26",
"value"=> 2),

array("day"=> "04-27",
"value"=> 4)
 );
 echo(json_encode($data1));
  
 ?>
```

I tried to change the yyyy as originally was to MM-dd then it adds that 12:00.

Here is photo of the chart:
[image: the chart]

Comment: Isn’t this the same question asked yesterday already – under a different account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263050/amchart-wrong-values

Comment: Yes, actually, i did not know it went, stackoverflow gave me an error that you cant post questions then i looked for it, didnt found it, but is here obvsly, am sorry

Comment: but do know what to do with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [skipEmptyPeriods](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Removing_empty_time_units) property and removing `baseInterval` to only show the specified values on the x-axis:

```
dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;
```

```js
// Haetan data omasta APistä 
fetch('https://users.metropolia.fi/~noorja/WSK12021/OTIUM02-offical/OTIUM02/API/hrv.php')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data1) => {
    //console.log(data1);
    // Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    // Create chart
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.paddingRight = 20;

    chart.data = data1;
    chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "HH:mm";

    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
    
    dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;    

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
    series.dataFields.dateX = "day";
    series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
    series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
    series.strokeWidth = 3;

    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
    chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
    chart.cursor.fullWidthLineX = true;
    chart.cursor.lineX.strokeWidth = 0;
    chart.cursor.lineX.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(2);
    chart.cursor.lineX.fillOpacity = 0.1;

    chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```